# IRC client connect to general channel

Tags: ubuntu, openstreetmap, irc, xchat2

I am using XChat as an IRC client. I am trying to get the OSM channel from [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IRC#Other_chat_rooms), but when I look for `#OSM` in the channel list I cannot find it.

I am connected to Ubuntu servers. Do I need to connect to the IRC server listed on this page in order to find the channel?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and SuperUser cover more general questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am connected to Ubuntu servers.

The Ubuntu channels are on the Freenode network. The OpenStreetMap  project also has a channel on Freenode as `#openstreetmap` instead of `#osm`.

> Do I need to connect to the IRC server listed on this page in order to find the channel?

Yes. In order to connect to an IRC channel, you must be connected to the same network. So to join the official OpenStreetMap IRC channel, you will need to connect to `irc.oftc.net` and then `/join #osm`.

Comment: Thanks, so how can I use both a channel that is on the ubuntu network and a channel that is on the OSM network on the same time?

Comment: @thebeancounter You should be able to open the server list and select "Connect in Tab" or something similar. I don't have access to XChat at the moment but will verify in a few hours.